# How to get Symfony and Twig to use Templates

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I am awfully new to Symfony 4 and Twig 2.

All I want to do is get the basic functionality of extending templates to work.

Unfortunately the documentation of [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html) and [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/) do not explain what I am looking for (Twig documentation is mostly just a collection of code with only minimal explanations). Or I don't understand... :)

This is simple.

I got the usual base.html.twig:

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}Old Content{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I only added some default text into the body block.

Next a simple file that should extend the one above:

**body.html.twig**

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    New content
{% endblock %}
```

To output all this I created a controller:

**baseController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class baseController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function base()
    {
        return $this->render('base.html.twig');
    }
}
?>
```

Tested the templates in [twigfiddle.com](https://twigfiddle.com/) and all worked well, so they are surely fine.

The above setup outputs the *base.html.twig* just fine (see the "Old Content" text, but completely ignore the *body.html.twig*. So the obvious question: what am I overlooking/which basic concept am I not grasping?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: `render('body.html.twig')` ? every page template you build will (probably) extend the base template. you render the page template not the base template (since the latter will be included in the former)

Comment: In public fuction base, if you return `return $this->render('body.html.twig');` you should see "New content"

Comment: Yes, then it outputs that the 'body.html.twig', but if I add another template file to extend the base file, say for the sylesheets (e.g. 'stylesheets.html.twig'), that one does not get output. With the render() I can get one template file processed, but several?

Comment: your body.html.twig should contain the recipe of how to render the body page (body isn't a good name for that). you can include other templates via the `include` function and block in twig, you can include other templates via the `embed` block in twig, you can include blocks from other templates via the `block` function in twig. you should not include templates that also extend the base template ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base.html.twig is your skeleton and body.html.twig is your page specific implementation. Your controller should always render the body.html.twig, which will override blocks found inside the extended base.html.twig.

Some examples from the top of my head:

base.html.twig:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% include 'header.html.twig' %}

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        {% include 'footer.html.twig' %}
    </body>
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</html>
```

home.html.twig:

```html
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>header of this page</h1>

    {% include 'newsletter-subscribe.html.twig' %}

    {% include 'greeting.html.twig' with { name: 'Max' } %}

    <p>Some content</p>
{% endblock %}
```

greeting.html.twig:

```html
Hello {{ name }}
```

just creat the header and footer yourself. ensure you render `home.html.twig` in your controller.

If you want to dive into it and must use nested blocks, make use of https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/parent.html

base.html.twig:

```html
{% block body %}
    Hello World
{% endblock %}
```

home.html.twig:

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {{ parent() }}
    how are you
{% endblock %}
```

should output `Hello world how are you`. I would discourage that function though, because the dependency is not clear from a designers perspective. Also be careful with embed, it has a higher impact on twig then include or simple blocks.

Comment: For the sake of it, I added {% block footer %}{% endblock %} after the {% body %} tag in the base template and created a footer.html.twig in addition to what I already got. This file opens with the line {% extends "base.html.twig" %} and then the {% block footer %} with some text. It doesn't extend the base file. So I am not understanding something basic. :)

Comment: Inside your `base.html.twig` is the definition of a block with a default value, `{% block body %}Old Content{% endblock %}`. The function `{% extends "base.html.twig" %}` will load all blocks from `base.html.twig` into the Twig engine.

Ensure that your controller returns `return $this->render('body.html.twig');` and not `return $this->render('base.html.twig');`

Comment: Ensured. It outputs the "New content" line in the browser. So the 'body.html.twig' file is definitely output. So that one works. No sign of the footer file, though. This means I have one template that gets processed, but not the second (I'd like a great many :).

Comment: Add a `{% block footer %}{% endblock %}` outside(!) any other block. You overwrite the block content if you define it.

Rethink your structure:
base.html.twig defines your HTML skeleton. On it includes the `<body>` tag. Inside the body tag you have multiple blocks like `{% block header %}{% endblock %}`, `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` and `{% block footer %}{% endblock %}`.

Do not try to nest blocks, as you overwrite them easily. If you want to include other "parts" (not blocks) try to use the {% include %} or {% extend %} inside your `body.html.twig`.

Comment: @Charles if you want to include a footer in your base template, you write in that template: `{{ include('footer.html.twig') }}`: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#including-other-templates I really like the twig docs, because they always provide examples. and your questions are literally answered there

Comment: Created {% block footer %}{% endblock %} under {% block body %}Old Content{% endblock %}. I have nothing nested in the 'base.html.twig'. That is fine.

Comment: @Jakumi I see. So I can use {% extends  ... %} really only once per Route? That might be my mistake. I thought {% extends  ... %} will care of any template I create.

Comment: @Charles I've edited my answer and added three examples. Just make sure you do not nest blocks

Comment: @Charles I would really advise to think of extends as a means to build a *page template*, stuff that should appear in every page goes into the base template, the base template defines blocks (spots to put stuff in) and the page templates overrides them. to add stuff from other files, `include` is your friend.

Comment: @Charles if you want to use something like extends more than once, there is `use` and `embed` as well: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/use.html , https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/embed.html

Comment: Yes. Your example shows what @Jakumi said. Need includes if I want several templates to extend another, not {% extends  ... %}. I obviously still need to understand the difference between includes and extends better.

Comment: Thank you to the both of you. This was most enlightening. :) I am a true beginner. Thank you for your patience and generosity.